# Neither old or new registration id is canonical

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have two registration ids in database one from the old version which used gcm.register() and the new one using instanceID.getToken

I sent a ghost notification to both of the registration ids which are of the same device. This is what I get.
Old registration id (before app update generated using gcm.register)

```
{
"multicast_id": 0000000,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
    "message_id": "0:1f9fd7ecd"
    }]
}
```

New Registration id (After app update, generated using instanceID.getToken):

```
{
"multicast_id": 0000000,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
    "message_id": "0:8ccf9fd7ecd"
    }]
}
```

How can I remove or update the old registration ID?
Please Help! Right now, I can't send notifications because of this. Since it will send double/duplicate notifications.

**EDIT(2015-09-19):** Google has acknowledged the issue and are working on it. 
https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in gcm which is now fixed.

Now if I send notification to old gcm id, it returns the new registration id as canoncial id.

Source: https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

You didn't receive any canonical IDs... instead you've received only a unique *message_id*.

> If you try to send a message using an old registration token, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical ID in the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to replace the registration token stored in your server with this canonical ID, as eventually the old registration token will stop working.

From: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids

The *canonical_ids* field indicates the amount of canonical ids in the results. The result array holds objects that indicate per *registration_id* what the message id is with an optional canonical id **or** if there has been an error.

You only have to update the registration id when in the corresponding result the *registration_id* field is included (this is the canonical id). The results are in the same order as the *registration_ids* in the request. That's how you map the result to the requested registration id(s).

Look at this documentation example, for instance:

```
{ "multicast_id": 216,
  "success": 3,
  "failure": 3,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:0408" },
    { "error": "Unavailable" },
    { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
    { "message_id": "1:1516" },
    { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
    { "error": "NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

From: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#example-responses

Comment: I am receiving the same response from both the registration ids. So, I can't remove or update the old registration id.